# how to set to call a function from the current object using settimer

Tags: javascript

```
function Something() {
  this.var1 = 0;
  this.var2 = 2;
  this.mytimer;
  this.getCars=function() {
    //some code
  };
  this.start = function(l) {
    this.updateTimer=setInterval("this.getCars();" , 5000);
  };
}

var smth = new Something();
smth.start();
```

When I type in this.getCars() it does not work. if the function is global declared and i put in for example just getCars it works.
I don't know how to work out this problem because setInterval becomes as parameter a String.

Can somebody help me put with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var me = this
setInterval(function() {me.getCars()}, 5000)
```

if you happen to be using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), you could also use the handy [bind](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) method:

```
setInterval(this.getCars.bind(this), 5000)
```

Comment: I am using JQuery. Can you be more specific of how you mean to use the bind method?

Comment: I don't believe that jQuery has a `bind` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Something() {
  this.var1 = 0;
  this.var2 = 2;
  this.mytimer;
  var me = this;
  this.getCars = function() {
    console.log(me.var2);
  };
  this.start = function(l) {
    me.updateTimer = setInterval(me.getCars, 1000);
  }
}

var smth = new Something();
smth.start();
```

The `console.log()` bit is Firefox/Firebug. Replace it with something else if you're not using that (although I would highly recommend developing with it).

Basically the problem is that when you call a function, even a method of an object, the way you call it determines the value of `this`. See [Method binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator#Method_binding) for more details. So what you do is fix the value of `this` as I've done in the above example (for methods).

Comment: Actually, since this.getCars is resolved to a function reference when setInterval is called, setInterval(this.getCars,1000) will also work fine. The problem is using 'this' in the getCars method. That is where using the 'me' var is really useful.